# HTML/JS: How to prevent a render before script execution?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, render, repaint

I've just noticed strange behaviour with rendering before script is being performed. I always thought, that there is no chance for browsers to dequeue a task from render queue and execute it before script tag, since this is a single thread. And as you will see, it's not true. There is a simple example of code below:

```js
console.log('SCRIPT EXECUTED')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>HTML</title>

    <script>
        requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
            console.log('RAF', performance.now());
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

One may see inconsistent output in console. Sometimes render comes up before script and vice versa. It may cause to flickering in UI for example.

Could anyone give a meaningful explanations of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External classic scripts are *parser-blocking*, i.e. the HTML parser will wait until the script's execution before continuing parsing the remaining of the document.

```html
<script src="data:text/javascript,console.log(document.body.children[document.body.children.length - 1].nodeName);"></script>
<span>Should log SCRIPT and not SPAN</span>
```

But to also be [*render-blocking*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#render-blocking-mechanism), they need to be in the `<head>` of the document.

```js
/*
 * Since StackSnippets do wrap the HTML & JS content in the <body>,
 * we use another <iframe> for our demo.
 * But StackSnippet's console isn't available there,
 * so we use postMessage and log from here.
 */
onmessage = ({data}) => console.log(...data);
```

```html
<iframe srcdoc="
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
        parent.postMessage(['RAF', performance.now()], '*');
      });
    </script>
    <script src='./script'></script>
    <script>
      parent.postMessage(['SCRIPT EXECUTED'], '*')
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
  </body>
</html>"></iframe>
```

Note that Firefox apparently doesn't support *render-blocking* yet.

Also, you may be interested in the [`blocking="render"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#blocking) attribute, which allows a `<script>` to not be parser blocking (`defer`, `async`, or `module`) while being *render-blocking*, though this is currently only available for external scripts, but [this might change](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/10034) in the near future.

```js
onmessage = ({data}) => console.log(...data);
/* In Chrome this logs
 * SCRIPT EXECUTED
 * H1
 * "RAF", a number
 */
```

```html
<iframe srcdoc="
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
        parent.postMessage(['RAF', performance.now()], '*');
      });
    </script>
    <script defer src='data:text/javascript,parent.postMessage([document.body.children[document.body.children.length - 1].nodeName], `*`);'></script>
    <script>
      parent.postMessage(['SCRIPT EXECUTED'], '*')
    </script>
  <head>
  <body>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
  </body>
</html>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Since script blocks render, why repaint occasionally occurs between ending of parsing html and javascript execution? (try to run my snippet above and ensure that raf (repaint) goes before script execution)

Comment: Did you read my answer? To block the rendering the script must be in the <head>, and even then, only Chrome does block the rendering.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. Each script blocks the rendering in browser, regardless it placed within the <head> or not. When engine catches a script tag further html parsing stops until the script is executed. And the rendering is blocked.
But you said script must be placed inside the <head> tag, only in this case it's going to block the rendering. That's why I am confused.

Comment: The script's execution does block the rendering, but here we are talking about the fetching of the scripts, this normally doesn't block the rendering, only the parsing of the document. For a script to block the rendering while it's fetching its resources, it must be in the head of the document.

Comment: Got you, that's true. And this doesn't correspond to my original question. I am curious not about how to block the rendering, but why browser permit repaint sometimes before script execution. Run out my snippet many times and you will see inconsistent logging. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Because when it tries to fetch the external script it will render what it already has parsed, since that external script isn't render-blocking, because it's not in the head.

Comment: In that approach it always should allow repaint, because it definitely need some time to fetch the script though. I have an idea, that in my case script might be fetched and executed before next repaint (under 16.6ms). And sometimes not, then repaint occurs. What do you think?

Comment: There is no reason it would always render, no. And it indeed has to do with when the monitor sends its VSync signal.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether it's an external script or an inline script - they are executed in the order they are encountered in the page.

The biggest culprit for the inconsistency in output is the method `requestAnimationFrame()`. As per its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) even if this script runs before `script.js` all the time, the output timing will depend on a lot of other factors like:

- Delay of time takes your browser to respond to your request
- Your display refresh rate
- Other browser-specific parameter that are used to improve performance and battery life.

So that means even if your scripts are being run in the correct order under the hood, the rendering timing will be off depending on how fast the browser reacts to your `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Comment: In chrome RAF comes at the beginning of each render, regardless of whether is renderQueue empty or not. In other words, it indicates repaint in browser. In my case one may notice an inconsistent order between renders and script execution.

Comment: I notice an inconsistent order too, but its because of how fast the browser responds. Can you clarify what you mean by chrome RAF comes at the beginning of each render?

Comment: Sure, check this out https://webperf.tips/tip/measuring-paint-time/

Answer (score 0):

This is the default arrangement to provide good user experience.
HTML won't wait till the javascript is executed. Even if it is a small slideshow which involves javascript, the content is more important to the user than the slideshow. Also if there is any user interaction which involves javascript, the user is going to interact only after the page is loaded. if at all you want the HTML to wait till javascript is loaded, you can use script defer tag for your javascript. It is as follows:

```
<body>

<!-- HTML content-->

<script defer>
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Code to be executed after HTML is loaded
       
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Please remember that the delay in HTML page loading could affect the SEO factors.